# Rotate a dragboard? JavaFX 8

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So I have an ImageView that I can drag and drop and when I click on it, it changes orientation. Problem is the dragView wich is the image displayed when you drag the object doesn't change orientation like the ImageView.
There seem to be no rotate, setRotate... So I've tried to rotate the image before doing what I do below but it didn't work.
Any idea on how to achieve this?

```
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    Dragboard db = this.bato.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    Image sourceImage = this.bato.getImage();

    db.setDragView(sourceImage, 20, 20);
    content.putImage(sourceImage);
    db.setContent(content);
    event.consume();    
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `bato` is an `ImageView`? Is the issue that you want the drag view to appear as a copy of the `ImageView` (with transforms etc), instead of as the source image of the `ImageView`?

Comment: Yes bato is an ImageView. And yes that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can take a snapshot of your `ImageView` and use the snapshot as the drag view (this works with any node, not just an image view):

```
Image dragView = bato.snapshot(null, null);
db.setDragView(dragView, 20, 20);
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I'm discovering Java FX 8 with this project, I had no idea we could do this